# My player shoot the bullets 90 dregrees off

Tags: java, lwjgl

This may be an easy task, but I cant figure it out.
This is a 2d game using the LWJGL library. I've created the player using openGL and the bullets with openGL. The bullets go 90 degrees more to the right.

Classes:

[Game class](http://pastebin.com/xUCb9KTM)

[Player class](http://pastebin.com/cYreMEVQ)

[Bullet class](http://pastebin.com/f460gdvy)

[Update class(not important)](http://pastebin.com/f460gdvy)

[Render class(not important)](http://pastebin.com/NdMsRQHp)

[image: demostration]

So, how can I fix that? If its only adding 90 degrees can you tell me how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LWJGL uses radians, so you need to add 90 to your degree value before converting to radians.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I just needed to add 90 like that **Math.toRadians(rotation.get(i) + 90)**

Comment: Yeah, inside the conversion to radians, sorry.